# zsh terminal can't open config?

Tags: github, ssh, terminal, zsh

Hello I am very new to using zsh terminal and am trying to set up my SSH key with github. According to [this tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) I have to open my /.ssh/config file and add my key. But after creating the file using `touch ~/.ssh/config` and then using the `open` command, the terminal goes opaque as if executing but then nothing happens. Please help!

[image]

Comment: you need to use an editor - like vi or nano, not the 'open' command

Comment: The link you posted doesn't have the words "config" or "touch" anywhere on it.

Comment: yes it does, please scroll and look at the shell commands. the previous answer solved my issue, I used ```# nano ~/.ssh/config``` to edit the config.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? BTW, _open_ is not a standard Linux command, so you better specify what OS you are using.

Comment: if you look at the github tutorial, it uses the ```open``` command to check if there is a config, and then the direction says 'open the config'. I understand that this may be obvious to you but it's really not to me, since it's my first time. I'm using macOS.

Comment: @ssarkar : I don't see anything like this in the page you posted. Actually, my intuitive idea would be that to add your SSH key, you would have to use a texteditor to put it into. Actually the page you linked to, does not anywhere use an `open` command. It uses several time the word `Open` (not `open`), but this is not surprising, since it is English text.

Comment: BTW: The page you linked to was obviously not written with particularily macOS in mind, since it mentions _GitBash_, which is used on Windows, not MacOS. Aside from this, MacOS indeed **does** have a command named [`open`](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/02/the-macos-open-command/), but I don't see how this would be related to your problem. I wonder: Did you perhaps post a wrong github link?

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for your clarification. I've uploaded the screenshot from the github link that shows the confusing part for me: https://imgur.com/a/TBHf1QI
I have learned a lot about zsh and bash from uploading this question and I certainly have a lot more to learn!

Comment: From my understanding, opening a file means using a texteditor, which also creates the file, but this is **not** something you are doing in a script (program). Of course if you use the MacOS `open` command on a file which does not exist, you get an error message: You can not open something which does not exist, in the same way as you can not sleep in a bed which does not exist.

Comment: that's clear to me now, but the confusion I'm referring to is that the command `open` is used in the github example to check whether the file exists, which would imply that if it DID exist, you would get a different message. but I'm now more knowledgeable on the subject and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your key to your `~/.ssh/config` (using, as noted, a [text editor](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/files-vi-nano-emacs)) is only needed to:

- reference a private SSH key which is not a default one (as listed in "[Checking for existing SSH keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys#checking-for-existing-ssh-keys)"), like `id_rsa`, `id_ecdsa`, or `id_ed25519`.
- using a shorter SSH URL

Meaning your config file can look like:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And your SSH URL becomes `gh:me/myRepository`.  (no more `git@github.com:...`)
You can test your SSH key with `ssh -Tv gh`.