# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.(Individual case!)

Tags: git, github, terminal, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm new at Linux and I could not open a connection to my authentication agent. I think I've done everything right so far. I just followed the GitHub instructions. I also tried it without sudo and it still didn't work.

**Here is my entire process:**

```
tomas@art:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 36078
tomas@art:~$ sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
tomas@art:~$ ls
desktop  documents  downloads  Downloads  public  Screenshots  snap  testkey  testkey.pub
tomas@art:~$ sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
tomas@art:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
/home/tomas/.ssh/testkey: No such file or directory
tomas@art:~$ sudo env "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
/home/tomas/.ssh/testkey: No such file or directory
tomas@art:~$ ls
desktop  documents  downloads  Downloads  public  Screenshots  snap  testkey  testkey.pub
tomas@art:~$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 36602
tomas@art:~$ sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
tomas@art:~$ eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 36608
tomas@art:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
/home/tomas/.ssh/testkey: No such file or directory
tomas@art:~$ sudo -s -H
root@art:/home/tomas# ls
desktop  documents  downloads  Downloads  public  Screenshots  snap  testkey  testkey.pub
root@art:/home/tomas# eval `ssh-agent`
Agent pid 36642
root@art:/home/tomas# ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
/root/.ssh/testkey: No such file or directory
root@art:/home/tomas# sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

My main goal with this, was to connect Git and GitHub. I've done the git and github tutorial for beginners on yt by freecodecamp.org. So if anyone came across this error in the past and knows how to solve it, please let me know how you did it ;) I would appreciate any support.

I tried so many solutions from stackoverflow and nothing worked:(

Comment: According to your `ls`, `testkey.pub` is not in your `.ssh` directory, you've got it at your toplevel.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `root` or `sudo` for any of those commands.
Everything should be done with your own account.

You will not find "`sudo`" in GitHub official instructions "[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)"

```bash
# start the ssh-agent in the background
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
```

---

The [OP Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20835143/tomas) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74998141/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent-individual-case/74999856?noredirect=1#comment132381718_74999856):

> I have already created the key, the issue was that I haven't put it in the `ssh` folder with that I mean there was not a `ssh` folder created.
>
> So I just executed this command: `ssh-add ~/(keyname)` just without the `.ssh` in front of the `/`.

Comment: it is still not working, I tried this                                                                         `tomas@art:~$ ls
desktop downloads public snap testkey.pub
documents  Downloads  Screenshots  testkey
tomas@art:~$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 6009
tomas@art:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey
/home/tomas/.ssh/testkey: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Tomas you need first to create your key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f /home/tomas/.ssh/testkey`. And if you are using a custom name for your private key file, you will need a `~/.ssh/config` file and a modified URL, as I recently [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74937091/6309).

Comment: I have already created the key, the issue was that I haven't put it in the ssh folder with that I mean there was not a ssh folder created. So I just executed this command: `ssh-add ~/(keyname)` just without the `.ssh` in front of the `/`. But thanks for your help, you have helped me on the jumps

Comment: @Tomas Great feedback, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the public/privet key file have correct permissions, you can give permissions using below command in Linux-

```
chmod 777 fileName
```

Comment: Isn't secure give 0777 permission to key files: _"These files contain sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not accessible by others (read/write/execute)"_ [ref. 1](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=profile-setting-up-public-key-authentication-over-ssh) [ref. 2](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1#FILES)