# git hub Permission denied (publickey), but only for one respository

Tags: git, github

I have many repositories(sites) within my github account, I used 2 different ones today, making branches, pushing merging..

I went to a third repository today (still within my git account like other 2). and I get

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository exists

I used 2 other from same account with last hour and still can  even now. They all have exact same persmissions

Why is only one site giving me this error and how can I fix?

I tried cloning it fresh, but it wont let me clone.

I have multiple SSH keys, could it be possible that one repository is using one, and the rest use the other (even thought I never configured them this way, but this site is oldest)? Both keys are saved in github config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github support got back to me (I had to pay them).

They recommend you use this in ~/.ssh/config, despite their help docs saying something else. Anyway, it worked

```
Host github.com *.github.net *.githubapp.com
  ForwardAgent no
  User yourusename
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
git -c core.sshCommand "ssh -Tv" clone git@github.com:me/myThirdRepo
```

You will see which key is used by default.

If it is not the right key, you would need a `~/.ssh/config` file (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74937091/6309)) to reference the right private key.

Comment: Hello VonC,
I get an error "ssh -Tv" is not a command, when I check git help, there isn't anything similar. What is long form of this command?

Comment: Also, I already checked local keys, my oldest key is no longer on my computer on git I have 3 including the one that is missing. If I just delete that reference on github, will github default back to one of the other 2 (which I have locally)

Comment: @JustinBlayney GitHub does not default to any key. Your local computer will use default SSH keys. You can see which one with `ssh -Tv`, since `ssh` should be in your PATH. What is your OS, shell and Git version?